# How do I open Zend Studio/Eclipse Files from a project in Explorer/Finder

Tags: eclipse, macos, zend-studio, finder

In dreamweaver they have  a "Reveal in Finder" function that opens a file that you add to the project in the the file management software of the OS (e.g. finder for the Mac).  I'm running Zend Studio on the Mac, this seems like a simple piece of functionality, yet I can't find it.  Any hints?

Comment: It looks like you have to do it through a plugin : http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by installing a plugin called PathTools

http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/